# Expanding IP ranges into single IP addresses using Linux bash command?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, ip

Which is the best method for me to handle this? I'm thinking awk might be the way to go perhaps, but not sure where to start even.
I have a text file, which contains IP addresses and ranges as per this example:

```
10.10.115.69
10.10.128.6 - 10.10.128.7
10.10.128.20
10.10.128.28
10.10.128.38 - 10.10.128.53
10.10.128.70 - 10.10.128.71
10.10.128.130 - 10.10.128.144
10.10.128.232 - 10.10.128.233
10.10.130.5
10.10.132.5
```

I'm trying to get them all into their own individual address. So as per above on the line '10.10.128.38 - 10.10.128.53' .. I would want that to convert to:

Expected output:

```
10.10.128.20
10.10.128.28
10.10.128.38
10.10.128.39
10.10.128.40
<snip>
10.10.128.52
10.10.128.53
10.10.128.70
10.10.128.71
<etc.>
```

Keeping of course the single host IPs included into output, just expanding the range parts.

Hope that makes sense.

Edit: Comments are suggesting this is a duplicate of another exact question. Please could someone link to it for me, as I'm not finding it. I am new here so not quite up to speed with things.

My expected output is as above, I'm not after a generator, rather a way to expand the ranges, the lines with '-' in them `<start IP> - <end_IP>` while keeping the single ones that are there still.

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is Python...

Comment: The duplicate is more specific but just don't exclude any subranges.

Comment: Not clear please be clear in your expected output and its conditions.

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear on my post, 1st time posting so still getting to grips with how this works. I've updated more on what I'm after.